# Find materials by bill of material

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have a **stlnr** and a **stlal** and I want to find all materials in a bill of material using these two fields. I have no idea how to do that, so please help :)

Answer (score 4):

the tables you need to look at are STKO (header), STAS (position selection) and STPO (positions). You need to know the type of BOM, which is in field STKO~STLTY. Using the type and your STLNR you can get the header row from table STKO. The STKO entry is connected to STAS using STLTY, STLNR and STLAL. Table STPO contains the actual BOM positions and is connected to STAS using STLTY, STLNR and STLKN (which is in STAS but not in STKO, which is why you need table STAS too).

You also may need to look at table STPU which is connected to STPO and contains subelements within a BOM position. In our system STPU is completly empty but that may not be the case in yours.

Comment: Note that the three tables STKO, STAS and STPO also log historical changes to the BOMs. They have a Counter field that auto-increments, so you need to be sure to only maintain rows with the highest Counter value to get the current BOMs. Each table also has 1-2 deletion flags for entries that you'll want to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the FM  `CABM_READ_BOM_ITEM`, you will need the following:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'CABM_READ_BOM_ITEM'
  EXPORTING
    i_stlty               = i_stlty
    i_stlnr               = i_stlnr
    i_stlal               = i_stlal
    i_date_from           = i_date_from
*   I_DATE_TO             = I_DATE_TO
*   I_WERKS               = I_WERKS
  TABLES
    exp_bom_item          = exp_bom_item
* EXCEPTIONS
*   NO_RECORD_FOUND       = 1
```

Which means you will need STLTY, as it is part of the key of STKO.